# How are floppy disk sectors numbered

Tags: disk, fat, floppy

I was wondering how are floppy disk sectors ordered, I am currently writing a program to access the root directory of a floppy disk (fat12 formated High Density), I can load it with debug at sector 13h but in assembly it is at head 1 track 0 sector 2 why is sector 13h, not at head 0 track 1 sector 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the sectors on the other side of the disk comes before the sectors on the second track on the first side.

Sectors 0 through 17 (11h) are found at head 0 track 0. Sectors 18 (12h) through 35 (23h) are found at head 1 track 0.

Logical sectors are numbered from zero up, but the sectors in a track are numbered from 1 to 18 (12h).

```
sector#  head  track  sector  usage
-------  ----  -----  ------  --------
 0  0h     0     0     1  1h  boot
 1  1h     0     0     2  2h  FAT 1
 2  2h     0     0     3  3h    |
 3  3h     0     0     4  4h    v
 4  4h     0     0     5  5h
 5  5h     0     0     6  6h
 6  6h     0     0     7  7h
 7  7h     0     0     8  8h
 8  8h     0     0     9  9h
 9  9h     0     0    10  ah
10  ah     0     0    11  bh  FAT 2
11  bh     0     0    12  ch    |
12  ch     0     0    13  dh    v
13  dh     0     0    14  eh
14  eh     0     0    15  fh
15  fh     0     0    16 10h
16 10h     0     0    17 11h
17 11h     0     0    18 12h
18 12h     1     0     1  1h
19 13h     1     0     2  2h  root
20 14h     1     0     3  3h    |
21 15h     1     0     4  4h    v
...
```